# Acces Layout Resource from Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, resources, scene

i am playing around with [Scene Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions#kotlin)

Im stuck getting the Layout Resource for getSceneFromLayout

```
val aScene: Scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.a_scene, this)
```

Ive tried something like this

```
val aScene: Scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, activity.resources.getLayout(R.layout.layout_overview), activity)
```

and

```
val aScene: Scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, view.resources.getLayout(R.id.layout_overview), activity)
```

But im not getting access to the layout files.

:)

Comment: First of all you can get activity context inside fragment with **requireActivity()**

 Inside you fragment oncreateView or OnViewCreated edit your code like this :

     val aScene: Scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.fragment_quiz, requireActivity())
     val anotherScene: Scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.fragment_content, requireActivity())

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i need to access a Layout File. R.layout.fragment_quiz throws an unknown resource error.

Comment: This layout parameter you are talking about is just a resource ID .Here in your code you do not need to get and infelate your layout .You just need a simple resource id .  R.layout.fragment_quiz is just a sample . you have to change fragment_quiz to your layout xml name.

Comment: In addition post your error here .Maybe others can help too.

Comment: The error is "Unresolved reference: layout_overview"

Comment: I deleted the android.R import and it somehow fixed itself :)

Comment: Great. Somethimes this happens with android studio and also happened for me too .A successful build will fix it .If this issue(Unresolved reference) occurred again use **clean project** then **rebuild** your project.when you rebuild the android.R  will be updated